# System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt versions differences

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, jwt

I am using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 5.6.0. Target framework is .NET Core 3.1. By using attribute  [JsonProperty] I am able to control serialization naming.
But after updating to version 6.5.0 this no longer works.
How can I control the naming in System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 6.5.0?

This is my data structure:

```
public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("pin-number")] //for 5.6.0
    //[JsonPropertyName("pin-number")] //for 6.5.0
    public string Pin { get; set; }
}
```

When adding this structure to the JWT token I am adding it as:

```
        var data = new Data
        {
            Pin = "1234"
        };
        payload.Add("data", data);
        var secToken = new JwtSecurityToken(header, payload);
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        string jwtToken = handler.WriteToken(secToken);
```

I get a token string. After decoding it I get this structure:
    {
      "pin-number": "1234"
    }
This is what I want.

After updating to version 6.5.0 it no longer works. I have updated the property attribute to  [JsonPropertyName], but it is ignored and the result looks like this:
    {
      "Pin": "1234"
    }

Comment: Are you using .net core's built in Json serializer. If so there are some things that are different / don't work. I had a different issue, but I fixed it by changing it over to NewtonSoft.

Comment: Might have been realted actually come to think about it, serialization of nested classes was where it went daft, I just wasn't doing a rename.